# Emacs: ac-slime for auto complete

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, common-lisp, slime

I am trying to add auto complete for *.lisp files. My slime setting is:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/slime/")
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      '((sbcl ("/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl" "--core" "/opt/sbcl/lib/sbcl/sbcl.core")
              :coding-system utf-8-unix
              :env ("SBCL_HOME=/opt/sbcl/lib/sbcl"))
        (ccl ("/opt/ccl/lx86cl64")
             :coding-system utf-8-unix)))
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

And ac-slime setting is:

```
(require 'ac-slime)
(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook 'set-up-slime-ac)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'set-up-slime-ac)
(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
  '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'slime-repl-mode))
```

Each time I type a word in *.lisp file, auto complete popups some candidates but after a second minibuffer outputs

```
error in process filter: Reply to canceled synchronous eval request 
tag=slime-result-6-19579 
sexp=(swank:simple-completions "de" (quote "COMMON-LISP-USER"))
```

and the popup stuck for a while. After that I can continue my selection.

My question is how to remove this error and stuck? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(this is too long for a comment)*

I don't know yet how all this work but I had the same issue and I can always reproduce it... And I found a workaround.

I don't know what *"Reply to canceled synchronous eval request"* means nor if there are really two synchronous eval requests.

And in case there are two such requests, I don't know what is causing them...

**However** by changing the timer before which the auto-completion menu and pop-up show up, I've been able to work around the issue.

If I eval this (say from my *.emacs* file):

```
(setq ac-auto-show-menu 0.1)
```

then I can reliably reproduce the error you have (and it blocks a while for me too).

If I modify the value a bit:

```
(setq ac-auto-show-menu 0.3)
```

Then there's no issue anymore.

It's a crappy workaround and I still think there's a serious (although maybe easy to fix) underlying bug hiding somewhere.

Comment: I don't know what to say now because of this damn setting. Actually ac-auto-show-menu set to 0.2/0.3 works here. Thanks @Cedric Martin.